# Shortcode doesn't work in specific plugin

Tags: plugins, shortcode

[Shortcode not working image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrAhY.jpg)

Shortcode: `[wpdts-weekday]`

[Functions-file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BlR2b.jpg)

I want to add a shortcode: [wpdts-weekday] from the plugin (WP Date and Time Shortcode) to a different plugin (Float Menu Light), but it doesn't work. See picture.

Can I add a function in functions.php to enable shortcode support for the Float Menu Light-plugin or perhaps add some code in the plugin folder itself?

```
<?php


/*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                   Theme Functions Here                       */                      
/*--------------------------------------------------------------*/


//---Theme Setup Options - Functions and Hooks
include('includes/theme-setup.php');

//---Adds Shortcodes
include('includes/theme-shortcodes.php');

//---Add Widgets
include('includes/theme-widgets.php');

/*--------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                   Your Functions Below                       */                      
/*--------------------------------------------------------------*/

add_filter('the_title', 'do_shortcode');
add_filter('widget_title', 'do_shortcode');

?>
```

As a side note the WP Date and Time Shortcode-plugin works everywhere else on the site.

Comment: For code, please post text instead of images - see [ask] and [mre]

Comment: I understand, will do that thanks!